# Does google search console, increase daily session if user leaves the page before the page load

Tags: session, google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm Using google search console to track my daily traffic. according to this [article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en), A session is a group of user interactions with your website that take place within a given time frame. 
My question is that does google analytics increases the daily session count if a user leaves the page, before the page is fully loaded for him?

Comment: To be nitpicky, Google Search Console does not influence sessions at all, it measures how often your page appears on Googles search result pages. To track session you do not use Search Console, you use Google Analytics, these are two different tools.

Answer (score 1):

From an [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-Analytics-track-new-sessions-Should-new-sessions-be-the-same-as-new-users-And-is-this-based-on-the-date-range-selected/answer/Scott-Richards-4?srid=3OMbp) to a [similar question](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-Analytics-track-new-sessions-Should-new-sessions-be-the-same-as-new-users-And-is-this-based-on-the-date-range-selected#):

> Sessions are tracked by initial engagement (loading of the javasctript file on your site and successful image request) until 30 minutes of inactivity. That means if you come to a site, leave and then come back within 30 minutes, that would still count as one session. But after that 30 minutes, it will be considered a new session on that device.